# Can I use NHibernate on Windows Phone 7?

Tags: nhibernate, windows-phone-7

Can I use NHibernate on Windows Phone 7?

Comment: AFAIK WP7 runs .NET CF4, and NHibernate doesn't run on CF.

Comment: @Mauricio For reference WP7 runs version 3.7 of the .NET Compact Framework.

Answer (score 3):

No, NHibernate does not support Windows Phone (or any Compact-Framework platform for that matter).  Entity Framework is also unsupported.

As far as ORMs go, the only one I actually know about (there may well be others that I don't know about) is the [OpenNETCF ORM](http://orm.codeplex.com), which is not fully implemented for WinPhone.  What that means is that there is a WinPhone project for the ORM (usign SQLite as a store) and that project's skeleton has been built (it will create the tables) but to get it to actually do CRUD operations, you would have to do some work.  I know someone who did it a while back as a test and it took him under a day.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know anything about NHibernate support of WP7. So far I've found following ORM's that support WP7:

- [Vici CoolStorage](http://viciproject.com/wiki/Projects/CoolStorage/Features)
- mentioned already [OpenNETCF.ORM Framework](http://orm.codeplex.com/)
- [Mono.Data.Sqlite.Orm](https://github.com/mattleibow/Mono.Data.Sqlite.Orm)

Hope it helps somebody.